# How to count the biggest size of the problem during some time period?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis

We assume that time of solving the problem $=f(n)$$\mu$s.
Now we have to calculate how big problem we can calculate for each time periods.

So there are:
$\lg n,
\sqrt{n},
n,
n\lg n,
n^2,
n^3,
2^n,
n!$,

How to calculate size of the biggest problem during those times periods?:
1s,
1min,
1h,
1 day,
1 month ,
1 year,
100 years

I completely don't know how to start.

Comment: by $\mu s$ you mean micro seconds? is $f(n)$ some proper complexity function?

Comment: For each pair of $f(n)$ and $t$ where $t$ is time, you have a formula: $t = f(n) \cdot \mu s$. Now you can do basic algebra and solve for $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freeman,

the answer is somewhat easy and you can do it with a simple calculator. I will assume that $\mu s$ represents a *microsecond*, *i.e.,* 0.000001 second.

Let's take for example the calculus for $n^2$. You need to answer which value of $n$ makes $0.000001 f(n^2) = time\_limit$. Thus, we have:

$0.000001 f(n^2) = 1 ~~~~~~~~\rightarrow n = 1000 ~~~~~~~~\text{(1 second)}$
$0.000001 f(n^2) = 60 ~~~~~~\rightarrow n = 7,745.97~\text{(1 minute)}$
$0.000001 f(n^2) = 3600 ~~\rightarrow n = 60,000 ~~~~\text{(1 hour)}$
$0.000001 f(n^2) = 72000 \rightarrow n = 268,328 ~~\text{(1 day)}$

You need to compute that for all combinations of time limit and growth factor.
Try writing a simple computer program to compute such numbers and plot all of them like the figure below. Hope you go well on your studies :)

[image: Plot of big-o notations]
P.S.: This figure was retrieved from [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/fr/practice/notes/sorting-and-searching-algorithms-time-complexities-cheat-sheet/).